# AngularJS routing keeps redirecting back to itself like it's in a loop

Tags: angularjs

I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myCustomApp">
    <body>
        <div id="body">

           <div ng-view></div>

        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/Js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

With the following

```
app.controller('SearchController', function ($scope) {
    init();
    function init() {
        alert("called");
    }
});
```

and the app declared like below:

```
var app = angular.module('myCustomApp', []);

    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/search',
                {
                    controller: 'SearchController',
                    templateUrl: '/js/partials/Search.html'
                })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/search' });

    });
```

The problem is that the page when browsing to the following it keeps refreshing the page like it's in a loop. Any ideas?

/#/search

Comment: Does it help you 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1417

Comment: Is there a <ng-view> control in the search.html? what does your template look like?

Comment: Would you be able to put together a Plunkr?

Comment: It looks to me like there's a problem in your declaration of the "search" route (either the controller of the view present an issue), and since your "otherwise" handler redirects to search, it will continue looping forever. The problem may be that you're calling the local function "init" before it's declaration. I would start by trying to switch them around.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var app = angular.module('myCustomApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Routing is not native in angular you need to add it in as a module.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.js

This is the CDN for the script for it.  I'd really suggest having a look at ui-router works very similarly but uses state or states to manage either the view or sections of the view.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

The documentation is really good and there are some great examples around.

Comment: This may in fact be the current solution to this issue, but you should be aware that this question is two years old, and the scripts listed in the question vary from what is referenced in your answer.

Comment: Thanks Claies, didn't notice the questions age.  I think that even 18 month ago you needed to ref ngRoute as a dependency.